# Kotlin data class extends Java class

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Java pojo class like this:

```
public class Event {
    private final List<String> urls;
    private final int totalPhotoCount;
    private final Owner owner;

    public Event(@NonNull List<String> photoUrls,
                 int totalPhotoCount,
                 @Nullable Owner owner) {
        urls = photoUrls;
        this.totalPhotoCount = totalPhotoCount;
        this.owner = owner;
    }


    @NonNull
    public List<String> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public int getTotalPhotoCount() {
        return totalPhotoCount;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

now I need to extend this class in a kotlin data class and add extra field - let's say String data. How can I achieve it? I cannot convert that class to kotlin

Comment: Kotlin just can't read a Java class, he just can read bytecode. so, I think you need first to transform this class into .class file.

Comment: You have an option to convert java to kotlin (when you right clic on your file in Android Studio) (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a .kt file and add the class like this:

```
data class EventSubclass(
        private val data: String,
        private val photoUrls: List<String>,
        private val totalPhoto: Int,
        private val mOwner: Owner
) : Event(photoUrls, totalPhoto, mOwner)
```